# Angular, ternary in ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ternary-operator

I have a ternary inside an ng-click to swap a value between 'bookmarks' and 'none'. The first click to change it to bookmarks works great but the second one does not. I think I have something wrong in the syntax or logic.
Here is the code:

```
ng-click="current = 'bookmarks' ? current = 'bookmarks' : current = 'none' "
```

I even print `{{current}}` on the screen and it does change from bookmarks once i've toggled it to that. Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Would it be an option to wrap this in a `setCurrent` function attached to the `scope`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ternary` expression is wrong.

`bookmarks`(*string*) is evaluated to `true` so, `current` will be always assigned `bookmarks`. This seems to work for the first time. However, for next clicks it will always be assigned as `bookmarks`.

Use the following expression:

```
ng-click = "current = (current == 'bookmarks') ? 'none' : 'bookmarks'"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for

```
ng-click="current = (current == 'bookmarks') ? 'none' : 'bookmarks' "
```